# Trying to stop jQuery autocomplete submitting form on select

Tags: jquery, autocomplete, form-submit

I am using a basic jQuery autocomplete box in a form but every time i click select one of the autocomplete suggestions it seems to be submitting the form. this is not expected behaviour. Anyone got any suggestions for me?

Comment: further testing: it seems to be redirecting me to undefined? still not sure what is causing it

Answer (score 0):

After some more searching I found a problem with another function related to hiding the link address display in chrome. as this is not a necessity now i have removed it for the time being.

The offending function below

> ```
> $("body").on('mouseover', 'a', function (e) {
>               var $link = $(this),
>         href = $link.attr('href') || $link.data("href");
>
>               $link.off('click.chrome');
>               $link.on('click.chrome', function () {window.location.href = href;})
>               .attr('data-href', href) //keeps track of the href value
>               .css({ cursor: 'pointer' })
>               .removeAttr('href'); // <- this is what stops Chrome to display status bar          });
> ```